# Is this a ManyToMany JPA/Hibernate relationship or there is another way to map this?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, persistence, seam

I'm getting started with JPA and created the following (simplified) tables;

```
airport
--------
id (pk)
city
code
...

trip
--------
id (pk)
originAirport_id  (fk)
destinationAirport_id  (fk)
...
```

I'm trying to map this in JPA/Hibernate.

In My trip object I created 2 airport objects:

```
private Airport airportFrom;
private Airport airportTo;
```

And I annotated the getters like this:

```
    @ManyToOne
public Airport getAirportFrom() {
    return airportFrom;
}

    @ManyToOne
public Airport getAirportTo() {
    return airportTo;
}
```

In my Airport class I created a HashSet of 'trip' objects

```
    private Set <Trip> trips = new HashSet<Trip>();
```

And annotated the getter:

```
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="airport")
public Set <Trip> getTrips() {
    return trips;
}
```

This would be simple to implement in SQL but I don't know how to annotate and implement that relationship in JPA/Hibernate.

Any tips?

Comment: +1 for well explained question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed a little detail. In the Airport class, the `Set<Trip>` trips you have must correspond to what is in the other table. I would suggest:

```
    public class Airport {
       private Set<Trip> fromTrips = new HashSet<Trip>();
       private Set<Trip> toTrips = new HashSet<Trip>();

       @OneToMany (mappedBy="airportFrom")
       public Set <Trip> getFromTrips() {
          return fromTrips;
       }
       @OneToMany (mappedBy="airportTo")
       public Set <Trip> getToTrips() {
          return fromTrips;
       }

    }
```

The "mappedBy" must point toward the name of a property in the Many class. Here, the two properties in Trip are airportFrom and airportTo.

So you have two Sets of Trips, the fromTrips and the toTrips. I hope you are ok with this?

---

**Edited**, after an excellent comment by *ChssPly76*, that would deserve to be an answer of its own. I would vote for it :-)

> If the association needs to be bi-directional that's the way to map it. I'm not sure it has to be, though - Airport has no business dealing with collections of trips. Consider making the association uni-directional instead and using a query when / if you need to find all the trips taken from / to airport in question (you'll be able to get a single list this way too).

Comment: +1. If the association needs to be bi-directional that's the way to map it. I'm not sure it has to be, though - Airport has no business dealing with collections of trips. Consider making the association uni-directional instead and using a query when / if you need to find all the trips taken from / to airport in question (you'll be able to get a single list this way too)

Comment: @ChssPly76 excellent comment, I agree. I included your comment in my answer. If you want to make it a separate answer, I think it deserves it, I will take it away. I voted +1 for you on a different answer anyway, you deserve it.

Comment: The solution offered by KLE works, although as well noted by ChssPly76 I shouldn't need it. While reading one Hibernate book I found the note 'One of the most common mistakes hibernate beginners do is try do use bi-direccional mappings everywhere.', which was exactly what I was doing.
The terms 'MappedBy', 'Inverse' and 'Owning' entity are also a great source of confusion (as I found out reading several contradictory posts elsewhere).
Long story short, the 'MappedBy' annotation should go in the 'One'side, the one that doesn't have the Foreign keys in the DB. Thanks!